# resource utilization as per schedule in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am working on car wash model, and I am running it for 100 hours but I want to store the data on daily basis ( after every 10 hours ) how can we do that. for example for every service block I have resource pool I want to see the utilization of resource pool in every 10 hours.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [cycle event](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/statecharts/events.html#timeout-event) that triggers every 10 hrs and writes data as you need it.

One simple way to print to the console: `traceln(myResourcePool.utilization()`

If you want to write to the dbase, check [this help article](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/querying.html#insert).